# How to convert back from $\cos$?

Tags: calculus

Let's say I have a $\cos(1000)$ which is $0.562379076290703$.
Now what I want to do is to get number $1000$ back. How can I convert back from $0.562379076290703$?

I tried $\arccos$ but it isn't what I need.

Comment: The cosine is periodic...

Comment: What does it mean?

Comment: It means that $\cos(x) = \cos(x + 2k\pi)$ and as well $\cos(x) = \cos (2k\pi  - x)$ for all integer $k$.  So there all infinite number of $x$ where $\cos x = \cos 1000$ you can't get $1000$ back.  You can only get an infinitionumber of possibilities where $\pm x + 2k\pi =1000$

Comment: The cosine is not an inyective  function (and hence not invertible), i.e. if we define $y=cos(x)$ there are infinite number of $x$ such that the equation is satisfied for a given value of $y$. The arccos is a function obtained in a restricted domain of the cosine function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the others have mentioned, trig functions are periodic. In this case, you’re using cosine.

$$\cos (x-4\pi) = \cos (x-2\pi) = \cos x = \cos (x+2\pi) = \cos (x+4\pi)$$

$$\cos (x-720) = \cos (x-360) = \cos x = \cos (x+360) = \cos (x+720)$$

Recall that angles can be thought of in terms of circles. A full revolution is $360°$ or $2\pi$ radians. Once a full revolution is done, the angles start over, which is why the statements above are true.

Hence, any angle repeats an infinite number of times by repeatedly adding/subtracting $360°$ or $2\pi$ radians. (For example, $30°$ is equivalent to $390°$, $750°$, etc. It is also equivalent to $-330°$, $-690°$, etc.) This can be generalized as follows for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. (All integer values of $n$, positive and negative.)

$$\cos (x+2\pi n) = \cos x$$

$$\cos (x+360n) = \cos x$$

When working with functions and their inverses, it is important to remember their domains and ranges.

The domain and range of $\cos x$ are $\color{blue}{0 \leq x \leq \pi}$ and $\color{purple}{-1 \leq y \leq -1}$ respectively.

For $\arccos x$, the domain and range will be inverted (since it’s an inverse): $\color{purple}{-1 \leq x \leq -1}$ and $\color{blue}{0 \leq y \leq \pi}$

As an example, if you calculate $\cos \big(\frac{13\pi}{6}\big)$, you will get the answer $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, but if you enter $\arccos \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, you will get $\frac{\pi}{6}$. This is because $\arccos x$ will return the angle within the range $0-2\pi$.

The same applies to your case. $1000$ radians is clearly out of the range of the $\arccos$ function, so it will return the value of that angle WITHIN that range.

As for how to get the $1000$ back, you just use the fact that $x = x+2\pi n$.

After entering $\arccos(\cos 1000)$, the value obtained is $0.973936$. This is the particular measure of the angle within the range.

But you know that $0.973936 = 0.973936 +2\pi n$. With the following equation, you can solve for $n$.

$$0.973936+2\pi n= 1000$$

$$n = 159$$

Therefore, your initial angle of $1000$ is really just $0.973936\cdot 159\cdot 2\pi n$.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that for $x\in[0,\pi]$

$$\arccos (\cos (x))= x$$

and therefore

$$\arccos (\cos (x+2k\pi))= x$$

then we can't reconstruct the original value for $X=x+2k\pi$.

Note that in this particular case since $X=1000=2\cdot 159\cdot \pi+x$ with $x\approx 0.9735$, we have

$$X=\arccos (\cos (1000))+2\cdot 159\cdot \pi$$

Answer (score 1):

The range of $\cos^{-1}$ is from $0$ to $\pi$. $\cos(1000 \pm 2\pi)$ will be equal to $0.562379076290703$ so there is no way to get the specific number $1000$ "back". It is "lost" once you take the $\cos$.

Answer (score 0):

$\cos1000^\circ= \cos280^\circ = \cos 1360^\circ$ etc.,

it repeats every $360^\circ$ or $2\pi$ so $\arcsin$ will always give you the lowest possible value

Comment: FWIW, the OP is using $1000$ radians, not degrees.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that after, but I still put in $2\pi$ for radian period

Comment: That's why I said FWIW...

Answer (score 0):

You have to figure out for what $k$ it is true that $k\pi \le M \le (k+1)\pi$.

In this case when $M = 1000$ we have $318\pi < 1000 < 319\pi$.

Then you do $v = \arccos 0.5623790762907029910782492266054 = 0.97353615844575016887940411711808$

We have $0 \le v \le \pi$.

As $k$ is even and we have $\cos (x + 2j\pi) = \cos x$ we add $k\pi + v = 1000$.  Or $318*pi + 0.97353615844575016887940411711808 = 1000$

If $k$ were odd we'd have to use $\cos x = \cos (-x)$ to get then $-\pi \le -v \le 0$ so $-v + (k+1)\pi = M$

......  This is assuming you you the first number was $1000$ in the first place and you are trying to get a known value *back*.  If you never knew that $M = 1000$ but are just told $\cos M =0.5623790762907029910782492266054$ and you need to solve for $M$ there are an infinite number of possible answers.  All $\pm 0.97353615844575016887940411711808 + 2j\pi$ for all integers $j$ will be a possible value, because for all $j$ we have $\cos (\pm 0.97353615844575016887940411711808 + 2j\pi) = 0.5623790762907029910782492266054$